# Can't get ZooKeeper cluster to work, election never happens

Tags: java, linux, configuration, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

This is my first time trying out ZooKeeper and while I could easily set it up for running in a single machine, getting it to run in a cluster of two machines is not working at all. I think it might be something wrong with my configuration, but doesn't look like I can find it.

[Here are the logs for server 1](https://gist.github.com/4277429#file-server_1-log)

[Here are the logs for server 2](https://gist.github.com/4277429#file-server_2-log)

And my configuration is as follows for both servers:

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
server.1=redis1:2888:3888
server.2=redis2:2888:3888
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

I'm running ZooKeeper 3.4.5 in an Ubuntu Linux box running OpenJDK 7. Tried to run on OpenJDK 6 but still got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the issue was that I had an **even** number of nodes, you need an **odd** number of nodes to be able to run an election (obviously). The documentation should be updated to cover that, since the basic example shows exactly 2 servers being configured.

Comment: you should be able to run an election with an even number of nodes.  With 2 nodes, both nodes have to be up for the election to complete.

Comment: As the logs show, both nodes were up and running and the election never happened. Once I got the third node in, the election did happen and my cluster is running fine now.

Comment: If you kill the current leader, do the other nodes agree on a new leader?

Answer (score 1):

Your config is invalid, specifically

```
server.1=redis1:2888:3888
server.2=redis1:2888:3888
```

if you run two instances on the same host you need to have different port numbers for each, better would be something like

```
server.1=localhost:3181:4181
server.2=localhost:3182:4182
```

Note that you should have the same server.# config for both server's config file.

Another option is to just use something like zkconf to generate all this for you: http://bit.ly/aQP9Yi

Comment: just a bad change to the real host names, both host names are different in the real config file.